# flutter sqllite not woring

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I m writing a flutter application and i m trying to learn using SQLite, as per document i added package in dependencies and run command to get it .

it gives error while compiling

```
  dependencies:
   flutter:
    sdk: flutter
   sqflite: ^1.1.5
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

i m expecting application to run but it gives error

```
PS D:\my\flutter\snapexpense_new> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              1.2s
Resolving dependencies...                                           3.8s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sqflite:lintClassPath'.
> Could not download kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.2.1)
   > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.2.1/kotlin-compiler-26.2.1.jar'.
      > Connection reset

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       120.2s (!)
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: thanx for a solution , due to internet malfunction it's unable to download but now it is working

Answer (score 0):

The day I was also with this problem but fortunately I settled after a lot of research time.

**First step**
you must download [kotlin-compiler.jar](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.2.1/kotlin-compiler-26.2.1.jar)

**Second step**
[image]

Open your project flutter go to the folder that is in the image above and paste the **kotlin-compiler.jar**

After all this done open your flutter project and update your dependencies, and when you finish back to run application.

For me it worked hope it works for you too.

Comment: Please mention why the method works, provide links to docs if any,